# Python Selenium: How to get cookies and format them to use in an http request

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

I am wondering the best way to get the cookies from a selenium webdriver instance (chromedriver), and convert them into a cookie string that can be passed as an http header. Here is the way I have tried doing it: getting the list of a dictionary per cookie that selenium provides, then manually adding equal signs and semicolons to format it as it would be in the Cookie header. The problem is: this does not work, on the site I'm testing it returns 500 internal server error, which I assume is caused by a. a bad handling of the request, and b. a bad request, specifically the cookie part.

```
cookies_list = driver.get_cookies()
cookieString = ""
for cookie in cookies_list[:-1]:
    cookieString = cookieString + cookie["name"] + "="+cookie["value"]+"; "

cookieString = cookieString  + cookies_list[-1]["name"] + "="+ cookies_list[-1]["value"]

print(cookieString)
```

Is there an easier method to do this and/or what is the problem with my formatting the cookie string that doesn't work.

Thank you sincerely for any help.

Answer (score 18):

```
all_cookies=self.driver.get_cookies();
cookies_dict = {}
for cookie in all_cookies:
    cookies_dict[cookie['name']] = cookie['value']
print(cookies_dict)
```

You can pass these to requests functions.

Comment: For anyone that needs a quick recap on how to add cookies in requests 
`response = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/posts', cookies=cookies_dict)`

Comment: Let's give dict comprehensions some love:  `cookies_dict = {cookie["name"]: cookie["value"] for cookie in all_cookies}`

Comment: self.driver.get_cookies() may get multi Cookies(because one page may use different domain names as data source, with SSO system it can auto login, and get a new Cookie),  so you should check cookie['domain'] first.

Answer (score 7):

You can save the current cookies as a python object using pickle. For example:

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver 

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

and later to add them back:

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver 

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use json to dump the cookies into an iterable which you could format:

```
import json
cookies_list = list(json.dumps(get_cookies))
```

Comment: -1 ... `json.dumps()` returns a string, and if you pass a string to `list()` you'll end up with a list of characters, instead of key-value pairs.