# modify class of a div in selenium using python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to change the page layout of a webpage from grid list to simple list but the problem it is not a dropdown or button. it is changing adding active class to the div element how can i achieve this using selenium in python

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-item title_mode active" id="0"><span class="fas fa-th-large fa-fw " aria-hidden="true"></span> Detailed</a>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-item title_mode " id="1"><span class="fas fa-th-large fa-fw " aria-hidden="true"></span> grid Detailed</a>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-item title_mode " id="2"><span class="fas fa-th-large fa-fw " aria-hidden="true"></span>list  Detailed</a>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-item title_mode " id="3"><span class="fas fa-th-large fa-fw " aria-hidden="true"></span>simple Detailed</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the `driver.execute_script` function to use Javascript to modify the class. Something like this:

```py
driver.execute_script("""
document.getElementById('0').classList.remove('active');
document.getElementById('1').classList.add('active');
""")
```

Just modifying the class may not work depending on how the website is set up.

Weirdly I cannot find any documentation of this function to reference, but [it is mentioned in the FAQ of selenium-python documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/faq.html?highlight=execute_script#how-to-scroll-down-to-the-bottom-of-a-page)

Comment: is there any way to get the cache of the website from chrome

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What cache do you mean exactly? A cached version of the site? The website's storage?

Comment: basically the data stored after visiting a website that is saved and changes will be there when revisited

Comment: I think you mean the cookies, where a website saves data locally. You can access this using `driver.get_cookies()` The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53097336/8708443) describes an example process of storing a website's cookies to a file to be retrieved later.